# Javacv: eigenface face recognition

Tags: java, javacv

hi im new to javacv and as ive searche in the internet i counter this piece of code and i decided to use  it but everytime i run the project it always return a java.lang.NumberFormatExcepti error. plesase help me to get through with this, please help me to fix this

```
    package com.shekhar.facedetection;

import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer;

public class facerecog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IplImage testImage = cvLoadImage("C://Users//Michelle//Desktop//jaffe//testna.jpg");

        File root = new File("C://Users//Michelle//Desktop//jaffe//happy");

        FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            }
        };

        File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

        MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

        int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

        int counter = 0;
        int label;

        IplImage img;
        IplImage grayImg;

        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath());

            label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

            grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

            cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

            images.put(counter, grayImg);

            labels[counter] = label;

            counter++;
        }

        IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

      //  FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
         FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
        // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

        faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

        cvCvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

        System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
    }
}
```

the error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "happy1.jpg"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.shekhar.facedetection.facerecog.main(facerecog.java:40)
```

the line 40

```
label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);
```

please help me with this help me

Comment: http://pcbje.com/2012/12/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv/#comment-3607 this is the site where i get the code please help me

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\\`

```
label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("-")[0]);
```

You should also replace your double  `/` in folder path (even if this does not affect you result)

```
C:/Users/Michelle/Desktop/jaffe/happy
```

Comment: aghm icannot remove the label because it was used in the counter

Comment: I mean that when you use `String.split()`, you don't need to escape `-`. But you problem is deeper, you try to get `1` from `happy1.jpg` with `image.getName().split("-")[0]`. This can't work

Comment: is there anything i can replace for the content of label

Comment: You are trying to get an integer from a String that is not (happy1.jpg). I cannot guess what you are trying to do

Comment: i get that sample code from here http://pcbje.com/2012/12/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv/#comment-3607

Comment: This piece of code depends on the naming convention of your jpg file, and try to extract an integer from it. It is up to you to do this. `label = counter` should do the job, this is just a label...